# The entity or complex type 'AdministratorModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am attempting to join two tables in a linq statement, and construct an 'Administrator Model' with a "Administrator Contract Model" attached to the parent model.

```
Dim response = (From a In db.Administrators
                    Join ac In db.AdministratorContracts
                            On a.NDE_Staff_ID Equals ac.NDE_Staff_ID
                    Order By a.LastName, a.FirstName
                    Select New AdministratorModel With {
                        .NDE_Staff_ID = a.NDE_Staff_ID,
                        .FirstName = a.FirstName,
                        .LastName = a.LastName,
                        .Contract = New AdministratorContractModel With {
                                            .AdministratorContractsID = ac.AdministratorContractsID,
                                            .NDE_Staff_ID = ac.NDE_Staff_ID,
                                            .NDE_Number = ac.NDE_Number,
                                            .ForYear = ac.ForYear,
                                            .Contract = ac.Contract,
                                            .ContractDays = ac.ContractDays,
                                            .Salary = ac.Salary,
                                            .Salary_AddComp = ac.Salary_AddComp,
                                            .Salary_Benefits = ac.Salary_Benefits,
                                            .Experience_System = ac.Experience_System,
                                            .Experience_Total = ac.Experience_Total,
                                            .EducationAttained = ac.EducationAttained,
                                            .BenefitsExplanation = ac.BenefitsExplanation,
                                            .AddCompExplanation = ac.AddCompExplanation}})
```

Comment: I have also tried this with no luck....

`Dim response = (From a In db.Administrators
                        Join ac In db.AdministratorContracts
                                On a.NDE_Staff_ID Equals ac.NDE_Staff_ID
                        Order By a.LastName, a.FirstName
                        Select New AdministratorModel With {
                            .NDE_Staff_ID = a.NDE_Staff_ID,
                            .FirstName = a.FirstName,
                            .LastName = a.LastName,
                            .Contract = ac})`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that LinqToEntities is trying to convert your query to SQL, but doesn't know anything about your model types (assuming that these are not the same as the database types).

If you enumerate the query before trying to create the types, it should work. Try calling ToList() after the OrderBy() and before the Select(). That will create an in-memory dataset of the database types, which is then detached from the database, allowing the rest of your code to work.

Note that if you want to do any filtering, you should do this before calling ToList(), as this will reduce the size of the in-memory dataset.